# Updating notification and activity simultaneously

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I have a button and when I press the button an ongoing notification with progress bar will show on notification area. I want my activity to have a corresponding progress bar that it shows progress same as progress bar in notification like downloading app on app store.
How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is that when I updating the notification in the service I can send a broadcast and receive it in the activity. So I can update the activity. But I don't know it is the best way or not.